# What is the convention for Java unit tests in a Grails project?

Tags: java, grails

I am creating a new Grails project that uses some Java code to do some of the "core" processing.  The java code will go in [project-home]/src/java.  Where should the unit tests for this Java classes go?  [project-home]/test/unit, intermingled with the groovy unit tests?  What is the convention for this scenario?

Thanks in advance,

Yvon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that you will gain anything by segregating tests on your java code from tests on your groovy code. Most likely, testing pure-java classes in a grails application will imply mocking your domain and other services (sometimes grails services). It is more convenient to test them in a GrailsUnitTestCase, all under unit/test

Regards,

Vincent Giguère